# Different fonts per language

Tags: fonts

I am using Greek, English babel. For some reason when I generate the pdf there are different fonts for greek and different for english. How can I use the same fonts and are the fonts machine dependent? See image:

[image]

Comment: Without showing the code you used to generate this it's hard to help. Are you using pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX?

Comment: You can use `xelatex` or `lualatex`and use any Opentype font on your system that has greek and latin letters. For instance, `Minion Pro`and  `Myriad Pro`, that come with Adobe Reader, have monotonic greek, cyrillic and latin alphabet. The maths fonts are another problem.

Comment: I use pdfLaTeX and I don't wan't to use XeLaTex.

Comment: As @AlanMunn said, you need to post the code. Create a Minimal Working Example which demonstrates the problem. For example, a complete small document which produces the output above. Post the code so people can reproduce the issue. Right now we have no means of figuring out how to adapt your code because we don't know what your current code is.

Comment: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html lists serif fonts, for example. The GFS and TeX Gyre fonts are a good bet for Latin and Greek support but there are other options. http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/tex-gyre/ describes TeX Gyre fonts. You need to pick fonts which support both scripts.

Comment: @ Jim Stanev: Then you will have to use one one of the font packages that offer both latin and greek in type 1 format. As far as I can remember `newtx` offers the possibility to use Linux Libertine as a Times-like font. Some fonts from the `gfs` bundle also have both greek ans latin fonts, but it  doesn't offer math support.

Comment: @cfr: Don't the TeX Gyre fonts exist only in Opentype format?

Comment: Thanks everyone, it was a font problem, I changed it and the letters were the same. A good looking package that I found is \usepackage{kerkis}.

Comment: @Bernard Nope. `ls <path to texmf tree>/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/` confirms what ctan tells me ;).

Comment: I used it with WinEdt which automaticaly installs it. http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kerkis/

Comment: By default, LaTeX uses Computer Modern fonts for the Latin alphabet and the CBfonts for Greek; the CBfonts were designed by Claudio Beccari to accompany Computer Modern; if you look closely, the design of the common letters is the same.

Comment: Related: [Specifying a different font for polytonic Greek in pdfTeX with Babel](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106790).

Answer (score 4):

This answer demonstrates some of the possibilities described in the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). The sample text is from Lou's answer. The sample maths is from `kerkis`'s documentation.

## Latin, Greek & Maths

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% uncomment as desired
% \usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
% \usepackage{gfsartemisia}
% \usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}
Φιμ αδ σαπιενθεμ εξπετενδα περσιπιθυρ. Αδ συμμο περσιπιθ ελεστραμ φις. Ευ σαυσαε περσιπιθυρ σιθ, ηις αυγυε ασομμοδαρε ευ. Ιν ορναθυς ινσωλενς δεσερυντ περ, εσθ ει αδμοδυμ ινσωλενς αντιωπαμ.

\selectlanguage{english}
This text will be in English. The elements within this block of text will also be set in the right language.

\[
    \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\]   

\end{document}
```

### Kerkis

This is the solution mentioned by the OP in comments on the original question:

[image: Kerkis]

### GFS Artemisia

Pulls in some elements from Nimbus Roman No9:

[image: GFS Artemisia]

### GFS Artemisia with Euler maths

[image: GFS Artemisia with Euler maths]

## Latin & Greek (No Maths)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% uncomment as required
% \usepackage{dejavu}
% \usepackage[default]{gfsbodoni}
% \usepackage{gfsdidot}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}
Φιμ αδ σαπιενθεμ εξπετενδα περσιπιθυρ. Αδ συμμο περσιπιθ ελεστραμ φις. Ευ σαυσαε περσιπιθυρ σιθ, ηις αυγυε ασομμοδαρε ευ. Ιν ορναθυς ινσωλενς δεσερυντ περ, εσθ ει αδμοδυμ ινσωλενς αντιωπαμ.

\selectlanguage{english}
This text will be in English. The elements within this block of text will also be set in the right language.

\end{document}
```

### DejaVu

[image: DejaVu]

### GFS Bodoni

[image: GFS Bodoni]

### GFS Didot

[image: GFS Didot]

### GFS Baskerville with BaskervaldADF

To combine fonts it is useful to define commands to combine font and language switches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{baskervald}% Latin Baskerville substitute; Libre Baskerville would be an alternative
\usepackage{gfsbaskerville}% Greek Baskerville
\newcommand{\switchtogreek}{%
  \fontencoding{LGR}\fontfamily{gfsbaskerville}\selectfont\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\switchtoenglish}{%
  \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{ybv}\selectfont\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}

\switchtogreek
Φιμ αδ σαπιενθεμ εξπετενδα περσιπιθυρ. Αδ συμμο περσιπιθ ελεστραμ φις. Ευ σαυσαε περσιπιθυρ σιθ, ηις αυγυε ασομμοδαρε ευ. Ιν ορναθυς ινσωλενς δεσερυντ περ, εσθ ει αδμοδυμ ινσωλενς αντιωπαμ.

\switchtoenglish
This text will be in English. The elements within this block of text will also be set in the right language.

\end{document}
```

[image: GFS Baskerville with BaskervaldADF]

Answer (score 2):

International language support may be helpful: see [this](http://www.sharelatex.com/learn/International_language_support) page for Examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Φιμ αδ σαπιενθεμ εξπετενδα περσιπιθυρ. Αδ συμμο περσιπιθ ελεστραμ φις. Ευ σαυσαε περσιπιθυρ σιθ, ηις αυγυε ασομμοδαρε ευ. Ιν ορναθυς ινσωλενς δεσερυντ περ, εσθ ει αδμοδυμ ινσωλενς αντιωπαμ.
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
This text will be in English. The elements within this 
block of text will also be set in the right language.

\begin{abstract}
A brief description of the main subject to be 
explained in the entire document.
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{greek}

Θε ασυμ μελιυς νονυμες φιμ, κυεμ περσεσυτι ρεπυδιανδαε φιξ εα. Δυο εα ιυσθο ρεπριμικυε, αλιι αεθερνο σριβενθυρ ατ πρω. Σιθ σονεθ νιηιλ ανιμαλ νε. Μει αδ βρυτε πωσε δισθας. Ιδ μεα χινς πριμα, δυο εα φερρι φασιλις ιμπερδιετ, ατ σασε φοσεντ λαβωραμυς υσυ. Εα φις κυεμ απειριαν.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on this site.  Please add some code to demonstrate how to answer the user's question.