# Match text and math Greek fonts with XCharter in pdflatex

Tags: newtxmath

I'd like to use the XCharter font with pdflatex and get the Greek font in text to match the Greek font in math.  I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106790/), but can't find the right font to use with it.  Maybe there's another approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[charter,scaled=1.07]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}

% From: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106790/
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\greektext}
  {\selectfont}
  {\fontfamily{artemisia}\selectfont}% Maybe change this?
  {}{}

\begin{document}
Make this \textit{\textgreek{αβγδ}} the same font
as this $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the association of the Greek letters with fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}

% fix a bad bug in XCharter
\let\LGRtextnu\textnu
\usepackage{XCharter}
% fix a bad bug in XCharter
\let\textnu\LGRtextnu
\usepackage[charter,scaled=1.07]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}

\DeclareSymbolFont{greekletters}{LGR}{artemisia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{greekletters}{bold}{LGR}{artemisia}{b}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ucgreekletters}{LGR}{artemisia}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{ucgreekletters}{bold}{LGR}{artemisia}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`a}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`b}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`g}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`d}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`e}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`h}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`j}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`i}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`k}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`l}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omicron}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`o}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`x}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`p}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`r}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`s}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`t}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`u}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`f}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`w}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`e}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`j}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`p}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`r}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`v}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{`f}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Alpha}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Beta}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Epsilon}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zeta}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`Z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Eta}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Iota}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Kappa}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mu}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Nu}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omicron}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Rho}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Tau}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Chi}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`Q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathord}{ucgreekletters}{`W}


\begin{document}

Make this \textit{\textgreek{αβγδ}} the same font
as this $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$.

\textit{\textgreek{αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω}}

$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\zeta\eta\theta\iota\kappa\lambda
\mu\nu\xi\omicron\pi\rho\sigma\tau\upsilon\phi\chi\psi\omega$

\textgreek{ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ}

$\Alpha\Beta\Gamma\Delta\Epsilon\Zeta\Eta\Theta\Iota\Kappa\Lambda
\Mu\Nu\Xi\Omicron\Pi\Rho\Sigma\Tau\Upsilon\Phi\Chi\Psi\Omega$

\end{document}
```

The “fix for the bad bug in `XCharter`” is necessary, because the package redefines `\textnu`, so breaking Greek support.

[image]

Comment: This is great, and I feel like you worked too hard because I was unclear.  But I was hoping to go the _other_ direction, that is, use the newtxmath Greek font in text (not artemisia in math).  I want to quote one Greek work in a document that's all English and math, and hoped for a consistent font.  But I don't know what to substitute for "artemisia" in the patch command.

Comment: @dedded There is no Greek font in newtxmath, only support for the math Greek symbols.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  When I use $\alpha$ I get a Greek letter alpha.  It must be in some font (and it doesn't appear to be cmr).  (Perhaps I'm using the word "font" incorrectly.  I'd like to put \textgreek{...} in text and get the same Greek glyphs that I get with newtxmath.)

Comment: @dedded What I meant is that there is not a full fledged font: only italic lowercase, for example.

Comment: Got it.  So I'd have to substitute what's used in math mode.